# Dragging and dropping tabs between browsers

Tags: x11, freedesktop, user-interface, wayland, drag-and-drop

When dragging a tab from Firefox to Chrome/Chromium, or the other way, why is it not accepted by the other browser? One would expect the tab that was dragged over to appear together with the other tabs.

Is this a problem with the X11 (or Wayland) protocol, a problem with the respective browsers or just a lack of standards for drag and drop between applications?

What would it take to make it possible? Start writing patches for Firefox and Chrome/Chromium while crossing the fingers that the patches would both be possible to write and be accepted? Contact the freedesktop.org people?

The user interaction is meaningful. Why is it not currently possible and what would it take to make it so?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible because this is not even d&d.

Dragging a tab from one browser does not mean that anything is put into the lipboard of the system (which is the central point of dragging and dropping between different applications).

So one has to define a protocol involving the clippboard for such a use case.

Also all participating programs have to adhere to this protocol.

Also what should be done in the browser where the tab is dropped to? Create a new tab and rerender the page? Firefox and Chrome use different rendering engines therefore it would be that there is no simple dropping.

Also what happens with login data? If I was authenticated in one browser and drag this page to another browser? What should happen with the login data?

I think this will be very difficult as there are too many things to honor...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that loading the dropped URL in a tab would be good enough, since the alternative would be too complex, for the reasons you mention. Also, while "drag and drop" currently involved the clipboard, in the context of X11, it does not have to be that way. "Drag and drop" is also the term used for a type of user interaction.

Comment: @Alexander even simply dropping the URL has the problems with authentication which I mentioned...

Comment: @Alexander D&D between different programs has to include the clipboard as ths is the only (reliable) way to communicate between very diferent applications. Insid the same application D&D is not handled via the system clipboard but something similar inside the application.

Comment: Simply dropping the URL would not automatically log you in and possibly not give the expected results, but for most sites it would direct you to a page where you have the opportunity to log in. Try for yourself with the url for this page.

Comment: It is incorrect that the clipboard is the only (reliable) way to communicate between very different applications. There are dbus and network connections, for example.

Comment: @Alexander but in this case the (normal) user will be iritated more than without dragging and dropping between different applications ("I was aready logged in, why do I have to log in again?").

Comment: I think the tradeoff is acceptable.

Comment: With a shared cookie cache and sites using OAuth2 (and probably some other outrageous assumptions), dragging and dropping the URL alone might work as "expected," but it wouldn't be terribly graceful. Or useful imho.

Comment: @HalosGhost, that's a good idea. I agree that it would not be terribly graceful. When it comes to usefulness, it's a matter of how users behave and what they expect. Drag and drop is much more widely used on OS X, for example, and users expect it to work. URLs/Tabs is not the only drag-and-droppable thing that could need a better or more standardized way of being implemented on top of Linux. It's about making it possible.

Comment: For the record, it really isn't a good idea. It'd be a hack at best.